# How to solve DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat error: "A UTC DateTime is being converted to text in a format that is only correct for local times."?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting this error while in Debug though the ToString() is executed:

> A UTC DateTime is being converted to text in a format that is only
>   correct for local times. This can happen when calling
>   DateTime.ToString using the 'z' format specifier, which will include a
>   local time zone offset in the output. In that case, either use the 'Z'
>   format specifier, which designates a UTC time, or use the 'o' format
>   string, which is the recommended way to persist a DateTime in text.
>   This can also occur when passing a DateTime to be serialized by
>   XmlConvert or DataSet. If using XmlConvert.ToString, pass in
>   XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind to serialize correctly. If
>   using DataSet, set the DateTimeMode on the DataColumn object to
>   DataSetDateTime.Utc.

```
public static string ToInterfaceString(this DateTime value)
{
    return value != DateTime.MinValue ? value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz") : string.Empty;
}
```

In the app that I've just starting to work on it is used this format in many places. So what should I do in fact? Replace zzz with Z?

Update 1:
the DateTime that is passed to my extension is initiated to:

```
DateTimeCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Weird thing is that if I pass to this extension some other DateTime objects I don't receive any error/warning.

Comment: Adrian, what do you want to do? Do you want to convert the `DateTime` to a string representation or want to persist it somewhere with the offset?

Comment: I need to convert current datetime + a certain offset (which is a user setting) to a string. That string is going to make part of a csv Message.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `o` format specifier? As pointed out here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8 it's ISO compliant and this allows you to import the date from the csv file using other applications.

Comment: Also neither `z` nor `zz` nor `zzz` are recommended for `DateTime` types.  Use `K` instead.  Reserve the z's for `DateTimeOffset` types.   This is covered in the remarks of each specifier [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier).

Answer (score 2):

It's a *green warning* only.

So - as you seem to know what you are doing - you can just comprehend the message (which is correct) and mark the checkbox to *Ignore this warning in the future*.

Comment: that is true. Is not a critical one. What I've noticed is that the DateTime property Kind is UTC. For that one appears only the error.
For other dateTime objects I use Kind is Unspecified. Is this the reason why the warning appears?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't apply to local time. I'm not quite sure about the reference to `Z`. Perhaps it is meant that `u` kan be used as the format specifier to append a `Z`to mark the string as UTC time. But you couldn't use that here.

Answer (score 0):

As the **DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat** error explains, the conversion of the date value to string with your defined date format is not usable with DateTime which have the property Kind set to 'Utc'. Even though this error is just a warning and your code should still work, the resulting date string you will get after such operation will be incorrect. This means that if you convert your date to string and will try to parse it again to DateTime, the resulting DateTime value will be different from your original DateTime value. The difference will be as large as your time zone offset from the UTC time is. This is a serious error and should not be ignored especially if your local time does not match the UTC time.

Example:

In this example I assume that the local time zone is 2 hours ahead of UTC time.

```
DateTime yourLocalTime = DateTime.Now;    // => 2020-05-15 08:00:00 => yourLocalTime.Kind = Local
DateTime yourTimeInUTC = DateTime.UtcNow; // => 2020-05-15 06:00:00 => yourTimeInUTC.Kind = Utc,  note hours, e.g. 6 vs 8

string dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz";

string testDateLocal = yourLocalTime.ToString( dateFormat ); // 2020-05-15T08:00:00+02:00 - This is correct date and time
string testDateUtc = yourTimeInUTC.ToString( dateFormat );   // 2020-05-15T06:00:00+02:00 - This date and time is 2 hours behind your actual date and time
```

To print the date and time string correctly using your date format you have to first convert your UTC date and time to the local date and time:

```
string testDateUtc2 = yourTimeInUTC.ToLocalTime().ToString( dateFormat ); // 2020-05-15T08:00:00+02:00 - This is correct date and time
```

To fix your code you should add conversion to the local time in your method:

```
public static string ToInterfaceString(this DateTime value)
{
    return value != DateTime.MinValue ? value.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz") : string.Empty;
}
```

You could also print UTC date and time instead of local date and time by replacing date format specifiers 'zzz' to 'Z'. However, in this case you will have a similar issue with conversion in case the DateTime passed to your method is not in UTC Kind, but e.g. in Local Kind and therefore, you have to always convert it to UTC before generating the string:

```
public static string ToInterfaceString(this DateTime value)
{
    return value != DateTime.MinValue ? value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") : string.Empty;
}
```

Printing of date and time without doing conversion can also be done by using date format specifier 'o', but then the generated date string format will differ based on supplied DateTime Kind and this date format also includes the milliseconds.

```
public static string ToInterfaceString(this DateTime value)
{
    return value != DateTime.MinValue ? value.ToString("o") : string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown and caught internally inside of ToString() method so the application will continue to run further. It's the only debugger who shows this.

It might initially look like a warning which is visible when debugging only but in fact, this code will generate valid results **only in case** when your computer time zone is UTC (seems there will be no internal exception in this case too). If your local time zone offset is, for example, UTC+02 than the result of:

```
new DateTime(2020,7,30,11,22,33, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:sszzz");
```

on your computer will be "2020-07-30T11:22:33+02:00" which doesn't make sense because the result obviously should have UTC offset as 00:00.

Also, of course, such internal exceptions is a bad thing for control flow and might affect your app performance if this occurs too often.

To avoid invalid .ToString() results and also internal exceptions you can just create DateTimeOffset from given DateTime and invoke .ToString() for it. So the code:

```
new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2020,7,30,11,22,33, DateTimeKind.Utc)).ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:sszzz");
```

will give expected result "2020-07-30T11:22:33+00:00" for any local time zone.

Another suggestion is to use the ["K" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier) which gives the correct results for both DateTime and DateTimerOffset.