# C# DateTime.ToString with zzz breaks in dotnet framework but not in dotnet core

Tags: c#, datetime

I have my local time in GMT +01:00 as the time of writing. I experience something, to me unexpected, when doing a ToString in the following way. Here we go:

Demonstrating the local system settings with +01:00 time zone (all these run green):

```
var myLocalDate = new DateTime(2020, 11, 25, 08, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);
Assert.AreEqual("2020-11-25T08:00:00+01:00", myLocalDate.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:sszzz"));
Assert.AreEqual(DateTimeKind.Local, myLocalDate.Kind);
Assert.AreEqual(myLocalDate, myLocalDate.ToLocalTime());
```

And now I create the same time, in utc, by manually subtracting an hour and specifying the "utc" as kind.
But when I call ToString, the time zone is written as +01:00 which I would expect to be +00:00:

```
var myUtcDate = new DateTime(2020, 11, 25, 07, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
// THIS Breaks:
Assert.AreEqual("2020-11-25T07:00:00+00:00", myUtcDate.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:sszzz"));
```

Error message:

> Message:
> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2020-11-25T07:00:00+00:00>. Actual:<2020-11-25T07:00:00+01:00>.

Do I miss something about datetimes and formats here, or is this maybe a known bug?

I run .Net Framework 4.8

This post is about the same issue, I see: [How to solve DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat error: "A UTC DateTime is being converted to text in a format that is only correct for local times."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346052/how-to-solve-datetimeinvalidlocalformat-error-a-utc-datetime-is-being-converte)

UPDATE:

Running the following program yields different results in dotnet framework and dotnet core (as mentioned by evk):

```
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2025, 11, 25, 07, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:sszzz"));
```

dotnet core prints:

> 2020-11-25T07:00:00+00:00

dotnet framework prints:

> 2020-11-25T07:00:00+01:00

Furthermore, when running dotnet framework in debug mode, the following debug assistant message shows up, but is ignored internally in the DateTime.ToString():

Managed Debugging Assistant 'DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat' : 'A UTC DateTime is being converted to text in a format that is only correct for local times. This can happen when calling DateTime.ToString using the 'z' format specifier, which will include a local time zone offset in the output. In that case, either use the 'Z' format specifier, which designates a UTC time, or use the 'o' format string, which is the recommended way to persist a DateTime in text. This can also occur when passing a DateTime to be serialized by XmlConvert or DataSet. If using XmlConvert.ToString, pass in XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind to serialize correctly. If using DataSet, set the DateTimeMode on the DataColumn object to DataSetDateTime.Utc. '

Comment: Whenever I asked myself "Is this a bug in the Framework or Compiler?" the answer was always, in 100% of the cases: "No".

Comment: move the myLocalDate.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:sszzz") and inspect the value your comparison is wrong also how valid is that format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff`i think ur missing a dot. or well is zz valid show where u are finding such values.

Comment: @UweKeim 99.99% and 100% with things like this....

Comment: @Seabizkit: I don't know about the OP, but I'm finding your comment very, very hard to understand. You might want to rewrite it more clearly.

Comment: @UweKeim: I'd go with 99.9% personally. There definitely *are* bugs in both the compiler and the framework, but I always treat my code with more suspicion first.

Comment: @JonSkeet perhaps this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @Seabizkit: I understand date/time formats very well - I just don't understand your *comment*. It's very imprecise - "move the [...]" - where to? Why? "inspect the value your comparison is wrong" - what do you mean by "wrong"? "how valid is that format MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff" - that isn't the format the OP is using - there's no dot missing. The OP isn't trying to get subsecond values. `zzz` is valid as a format specifier, as documented in the very page you linked to. I don't know what you were trying to say in the comment, but I believe it was unclear, incorrect or both.

Comment: one race Seabiscuit was not destined to win I fear

Comment: @JonSkeet apologies the question was updated a little, and apologies I did not know that `dd\T` the slash was valid escape char. Saying that a link, as i did could of been  provided in the question and the syntax explained..., it just felt like, take it out of the one liner, inspect the value, if an exception is happening about the format, then google the format. Sorry for my short none understandable comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's behaving as documented. From the [documentation of the `zzz` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier) (emphasis mine):

> With `DateTime` values, the "zzz" custom format specifier represents the signed offset of the local operating system's time zone from UTC, measured in hours and minutes. **It doesn't reflect the value of an instance's `DateTime.Kind` property**. For this reason, the "zzz" format specifier is not recommended for use with `DateTime` values.

Arguably that's unfortunate, but it's not a bug.

Note that .NET Core (and .NET 5.0) apparently *doesn't* behave as documented. While you could argue it's "fixed" in .NET Core, I'd suggest that behaving in an undocumented way is a bug in itself, and one that could make code migration harder than expected.

I suggest you follow the recommendation in the docs, and avoid using `zzz` with `DateTime` values. I'd *also* suggest using my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library instead, where there isn't the ambiguity in terms of a value "maybe being local, or maybe being UTC", but that's a *slightly* different matter. (I wouldn't expect you to run into this problem using Noda Time, and your other date/time code would hopefully be clearer.)

Comment: Interesting that in .NET 4.8, when debugging from Visual Studio, some kind of "debugging assistant" I see for the first time breaks execution on `ToString` and tells me basically what you wrote here (that UTC datetime being converted using local format specifiers). It's not an exception (execution then can continue).

Comment: And in .NET Core it seems to be fixed, and OP's test passes fine.

Comment: @jon Thanks for clearing this out, and I agree, very unfortunate.

Comment: @Evk Thank you for testing out and concluding that this behaviour was actually corrected in dotnet core.

Comment: @Evk: That's not good - that means it's violating the documented behavior...

Comment: I just checked myself. Dotnet core renders a different result than dotnet framework.
To test out, run this in a console app: Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2025, 11, 25, 07, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:sszzz"));

Comment: @StephanRyer: I'll use June personally, as my machine is in the UK time zone... right now I'd see 00:00 either way.

Comment: @StephanRyer: But yes, I've reproduced it. Weird. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I just changed the post title to reflect you guys' findings.